# Add Phone tag and Email Tag in Contact URI?

Tags: android

I can retrieve the contact details only having name, phonenumber and email using

```
**ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone ,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI** and 
**Email.CONTENT_URI.**
```

I have to add the Phone tag [that means it is a personal number or home number etc] and Email tag [means is a company email or personel Email etc] to the display. Which function I have to use to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the phone and email you can also check the `Type` of the returned phone and email by using the following code:

```
String type;

int contactPhoneType = cursorObject.getInt(cursorObject.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKind‌​s‌​.Phone.TYPE))

if(contactPhoneType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME){
 //Logic to set the type tag
}

switch(contactPhoneType){
case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME: 
type = "Home";
break;

case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
type = "Mobile";
break;

case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
type = "Work"
break;
}
```

and for Email use the following:

```
int contactEmailType = cursorObject.getInt(cursorObject.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE))

if(contactEmailType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK){
   //logic to set the email type tag
}
```

All other types can be checked by using the `TYPE` member variables of `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` and `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email`.

Comment: Will I get the phone type if I add this line.......... int contactPhoneType = cursorObject.getInt(cursorObject.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE))... only and display the contactPhoneType  to the ListView .

Comment: You will get the phone type as a `int` value by using `cursorObject.getInt(cursorObject.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds‌​.Phone.TYPE))`. This `int` value is just an INDICATOR for the `Type` of the phone number. For Example 1 represents TYPE_HOME, 2 represents TYPE_MOBILE etc. Use a `Switch` block to check the value of the `int` and thereafter implement your logic.

Comment: Check the following link to get all the phone type info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html#TYPE_HOME

Comment: I have used this code and it has worked for me. Do let me know if it has worked for you as well.

Comment: I see the Constant value 1 for Home and 2 for Type Mobile,what it mean .....you have any URL link as an example. the android website is very tough to a beginner

Comment: I have edit my answer to check three Phone types which you can extend to check the other types as well. Also the same approach can be used to check the email types.

Comment: Thank you arun, I didn't expect you to do this much coding to me , will check and inform you.

Comment: Arun, when I run the code it shows  application stopped unexpectedly and force close, check this link please (  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188037/phone-type-and-email-type-not-working  )