# Phone type and Email type not working?

Tags: android

The phone type and Email type in my project has some problem.I am using 2.1 platform, there was no problem in my project before adding the Phone type and the Email type, after using these Phone type and Email type when I try to run the project it open a message box and shows application stopped and force close. My xml file has a Button and the ListView. i am using this code.

**code**

```
 public class GetAllDatas extends Activity {

ListView lvItem;
private Button btnAdd;
String Ptype, Etype;
int contactPhoneType;

String displayName="", emailAddress="", phoneNumber="";
ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.lvitems); 
    btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);

    itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist);
    lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            readContacts();
        }
    });

} 

private void readContacts()
{
    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);


    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        displayName  = "" ;
        ArrayList<String> phoneNumber  = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> emailAddress  = new ArrayList<String>();

        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));       
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        /*                   Email                   */ 

        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) 
        { 
            emailAddress.add(emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA)));

        } 

         contactPhoneType = emails.getInt(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

        switch(contactPhoneType){
        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME: 
        Etype = "Home";
        break;

        }


        emails.close(); 


      /*            Phone Number and Type   */ 

        if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
        {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
           while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
            {
                 phoneNumber.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));                               
           }

            contactPhoneType = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));


           switch(contactPhoneType){
           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME: 
           Ptype = "Home";
           break;

           }


            pCur.close();  
        }   

int phoneNumberCount = phoneNumber.size();
int emailCount = emailAddress.size();

// Add arraylist data to contactlist..

if(phoneNumberCount > emailCount) {

    for (int i=0; i<phoneNumberCount; i++)
      {
        if(emailCount>i)
          {
           contactlist.add(displayName +  " , " +  Ptype + " , " + phoneNumber.get(i) + " , " + Etype + " , " + emailAddress.get(i) + "\n");    
           }
        else
        {
          contactlist.add(displayName + " , " +  Ptype + " , " + phoneNumber.get(i) + " , " + " , " + "\n");
        } 
       }
    }
    else  
       {
        for (int i=0; i<emailCount; i++) 
         {
        if(phoneNumberCount>i)
          {
            contactlist.add(displayName + " , " + Ptype + " , " + phoneNumber.get(i) + " , " +  Etype + " , " + emailAddress.get(i) + "\n"); 
          }
        else
        { 
          contactlist.add(displayName + " , " + " , " + " , " + Etype + " , " + emailAddress.get(i) +  "\n");
        }
      }
    }      
    }
    Collections.sort(contactlist);
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cursor.close(); 
}
```

}

**Logcat**

```
06-26 13:31:16.213: E/AndroidRuntime(449): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to   uncaught exception
06-26 13:31:16.224: E/AndroidRuntime(449): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
06-26 13:31:16.224: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
06-26 13:31:16.224: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
06-26 13:31:16.224: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:84)
06-26 13:31:16.224: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getInt(CursorWrapper.java:123)
06-26 13:31:16.224: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at com.abhi.GetAllDatas.readContacts(GetAllDatas.java:71)
06-26 13:31:16.224: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at com.abhi.GetAllDatas.access$0(GetAllDatas.java:47)
06-26 13:31:16.224: E/AndroidRuntime(449):  at com.abhi.GetAllDatas$1.onClick(GetAllDatas.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error in your code.  You are checking the phoneType as well as the emailtype after moving the cursor beyond the last record (pCur.moveToNext() after the `while` loop goes beyond the last record). You need to check it within the `while` loop and not after if. Change the following:

```
while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
        {
             phoneNumber.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))); 

             int contactPhoneType = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

             switch(contactPhoneType){
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME: 
                     Ptype = "Home";
                     break;
           }                  
       }
```

do the same correction for the emailType as well.

Comment: I got the answer.your code is right, first a Great Thanks to you  but a contact having 2 numbers and 2 emails for both it shows the same type. I will try to correct it. Don't forget me...

Answer (score 0):

Might it be this line:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext())
```

To me, that looks like you are moving the cursor before you've even read the first cursor position, and you're getting an CursorIndexOOB exeption.

Try a do-while loop instead, see if that helps.

Also, check that your application has the permission to read contact data.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
```

Answer (score 0):

as looks problem is with index

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
```

gor getting the Phone.TYPE can try below code as per this http://www.vtgroup.com/#ContactsContract

```
    //  Get all phone numbers.
    //
    Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
        Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
        int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
        switch (type) {
            case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                // do something with the Home number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                // do something with the Mobile number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                // do something with the Work number here...
                break;
            }
    }
    phones.close();
```

Comment: Email Type and Phone Type coming but not in the proper order I added HOME, WORK MOBILE and OTHERS ....but comes randomly for some contacts \

Comment: you mean any change is required for this statement ?

Comment: I checked the code and edited as I can without getting the error but no difference , CODE33 need the actual error to refer and me also

Answer (score 0):

As told by Dheeresh you have to change that condition

Comment: changed but no difference,I got the same answer with random Phone and Email Type

Comment: I check your code but  I didn't get the solution , I have to refer You ask dheeresh to the actual problem.